# JIntellitype with java

Tags: java, hotkeys

How is it possible to use JIntellitype in Java? If that's not possible, how would I use Hotkey on a system tray menu, which would act even if application is not in focus.

However, I have not been able to get JIntellitype to work on MAC OSX.

How can I make this work on a mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old, but it has no answer.  JIntellitype uses that Java Native Interface (JNI) to leverage C/C++ that talks to the operating system's API directly thus bypassing the sandbox limitations of the JVM.  As you have already noticed, the native C/C++ code is platform dependent and will only run on Windows in this case.  There are similar projects for Linux ([JxGrabKey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxgrabkey/)) and Mac OSX ([OSSupport](https://bitbucket.org/agynamix/ossupport-connector/src)), however, the API for each platform differs.  If you need better cross platform support, you can try using [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook).